# cannot convert argument 1 from 'sf::RenderWindow *' to 'sf::RenderWindow &'

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

I've been making a game in SFML and I got this problem:

cannot convert argument 1 from 'sf::RenderWindow *' to 'sf::RenderWindow &'

I know the basics of pointers & stuff,but I am still not sure how to properly use them and so I've no idea what this means.
But anyways, in game class:

```
class Game {
public:
    RenderWindow renderWindow;
private:
    Player player{renderWindow,100,100 };
}
```

I initialize renderWindow and player:

```
class Player
{
public:
   Player(RenderWindow &renderWindow,int x,int y) {
      draw(renderWindow,x, y);
}
      void draw(RenderWindow &renderWindow,int x,int y);
private:
     int x, y;
};
```

Player.cpp:

```
void Player::draw(RenderWindow &renderWindow,int x,int y)
{
    //do stuff using renderWindow
}
```

And I think I am supposed to be calling constructor with a reference, otherwise I get errors with draw() functions- that it cannot references as it is deleted.
I also tried using pointers, but I am not sure how to properly call this constructor/function.

Comment: I don't see anything of type `RenderWindow*` in the code you posted.  Can you post the exact line that is causing the error?  (The compiler output should show you a filename and line number.)

Comment: There is propably a bug in code you are not showing. Where else do you call draw? How do you pass the value there? Usually the compiler prints out the line in which the error occured too.

Comment: The exact line is line 5 in Game.h class. That is the only time I call draw.

Comment: And how does that call look?

Comment: It's in the Player constructor in the post upside.  It looks like this: draw(renderWindow,x, y);

Comment: Based on the error message you will probably need to call it like `draw(*renderWindow, x, y);`.  But it's impossible to tell without seeing all of the surrounding code.  (Feel free to edit your post to add more context.)

Comment: Oh,nevermind I fixed it somehow...

Answer (score 1):

The token & means reference, while * means pointer. You are trying to pass a pointer to a function that requires a reference. Simply change

```
class Player
{
public:
   Player(RenderWindow &renderWindow,int x,int y) {
      draw(renderWindow,x, y);
}
      void draw(RenderWindow &renderWindow,int x,int y);
private:
     int x, y;
};
```

to

```
class Player
{
public:
   Player(RenderWindow *renderWindow,int x,int y) {
      draw(renderWindow,x, y);
}
      void draw(RenderWindow *renderWindow,int x,int y);
private:
     int x, y;
};
```

and

```
void Player::draw(RenderWindow &renderWindow,int x,int y)
{
    //do stuff using renderWindow
}
```

to

```
void Player::draw(RenderWindow *renderWindow,int x,int y)
{
    //do stuff using renderWindow
}
```